# My calculator program is not recognising first method and subtracts for both methods, why?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner taken = new Scanner(System.in);
        int fnum;
        int snum;
        int ans;
        String meth;

        System.out.println("Please type method you wish to use:");
        meth = taken.nextLine();

        if (meth == "+" || meth == "plus") {
            System.out.println("Please enter the First number:");
            fnum = taken.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter the Second number:");
            snum = taken.nextInt();
            ans = fnum + snum; // This is the bit it misses even if the user goes through this method.
            System.out.println("The answer is " + ans);
        } else {
            subCalc subCalcObject = new subCalc();
            subCalcObject.subCalculator();
        }
    }

}
```

Like whats in the title my program does not + the numbers which is whats supposed to be done in the first statement and always subtracts no matter what method is chosen.

Comment: Use a debugger and observe what is the value of `meth` before the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `equals` to compare the strings. `==` will return `false` so that you always go the `else` code.

```
if (meth.equals("+") || meth.equals("plus"))
```

`equals` checks for value equality while `==` checks for reference equality. So, when you do

```
meth = taken.nextLine();
```

`meth` is a different object from the constant strings "+" and "plus", so reference equality check will fail.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use equals and not ==

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner taken = new Scanner(System.in);
    int fnum;
    int snum;
    int ans;
    String meth;

    System.out.println("Please type method you wish to use:");
    meth = taken.nextLine();

    if (meth.equals("+") || meth.equals("plus")){


        System.out.println("Please enter the First number:");
        fnum = taken.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the Second number:");
        snum = taken.nextInt();
        ans = fnum + snum; // This is the bit it misses even if the user goes through     this method.
        System.out.println("The answer is " + ans);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 if (meth == "+" || meth == "plus"){
```

To

```
 if ("+".equals(meth) || "plus".equals(meth) ){
```

Now you can see there are adding.